# How do I use a JButton's Model?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jbutton

Java Swing builds on the (approximate) concept of MVC and its UI components usually have some kind of Model associated to them.

So what is the Model for a `JButton`? I'm not very familiar to Java Swing. Is it an instance of the `javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel` class? Or an implementation of the `javax.swing.ButtonModel` interface?

Also, some people say [we should rarely extend](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/317495/when-should-i-extend-a-java-swing-class) a Java Swing component.

So within that spirit I have the concept of a "piece button" in a simple color-guessing game which is a button tied to a `Piece` (the piece simply represents a single color, I could as well have used `Color` instead). It should not extend `JButton` because it is not modifying any of its functionality. Also using composition doesn't seem to make sense in that case.

So what should I do? Should I add `Piece` to the button's Model? If so, how should I do that?

Or should I ignore the previous statements and extend `JButton` instead? I would then have something like this:

```
public final class PieceButton extends JButton {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Piece piece;

    public PieceButton(Piece piece, int iconSize) {
        this.piece = Objects.requireNonNull(piece);
        setIcon(new ColorRoundIcon(iconSize, piece.getColor()));
    }

    public Piece getPiece() {
        return piece;
    }
}
```

So what is the best (OOP-wise) approach?

Comment: Maybe method [putClientProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) is appropriate for your situation?

Comment: `ButtonModel` is an `interface` which describes the basic concept that needs to be implement in order for it to work.  `DefaultButtonModel` is a "default" implementation, which means you don't need to create a new type of model every time you want to create a button - because that would get annoying fast .  To my mind, you should have a seperate model which represents the "sequence" of colors in the guessing game.  You then use what ever UI elements you need/want to then represent this model in the way you want

Comment: *"Java Swing builds on the (approximate) concept of MVC"* - Actually, if you look into the history and origins of MVC - you'll find that Swing is a closer "approximation" of the original intent then what is taught now days ... but now I'm just nit picking 

Comment: @Abra I'm not sure if that's the intended usage of that method. But on the other hand what else would it be used for? But I'm hesitant that in that way the data is not in the model, though.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see, because color is also a property of button. But what if it were animals instead? I would have to put them somewhere in the buttons' models -- at least that's how I see it. What would you do? Oh wait...

Comment: @Piovezan Not really, it has nothing to do with the model, directly.  Since the "game model" can change, it would be easier to simply make use of the existing functionality of the component directly - this doesn't mean you "can't" make your own button models, but I would consider it a lot of extra work for little benefit - but that's me

Comment: If you don't like `PieceButton` to extends `JButton` (inheritance)  you can use composition. `PieceButton` can have a `JButton` and a getter to return it `JButton getButton()`.

Comment: @c0der I tried composition initially but it caused some violations to the Law of Demeter and caused one more problem in the code. I also think it doesn't make sense in that case. I would either use a ButtonModel or use inheritance, but MadProgrammer's suggestion (if I understand it correctly) is better, to use simple buttons with known functionality and change game logic in a separate game model (as in MVC, but not the MVC of Java Swing, a manual implementation of MVC instead). That's what my project is about BTW.